# after angular 6 update : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

When I update the `dist/ folder(ng build --prod --service-worker)` and restart nginx.
I go back to my website(fctoernooi.nl) and it will not load, giving the error : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ().....js`.
I created new js-files so this seems obvious.
It looks like the service-worker does not see there is an update. Do I miss or forget something in the service-worker-configuration?

Can anybody help? I could not find much about problems when updating angular websites.